# Magento extend getCssJsHtml()

Tags: magento, extend

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

I have this going on:

```
app/code/local/Company/etc/confix.xml:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Core>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Core>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <core>
              <rewrite>
                  <store>Company_Page_block_Html_Head</Store>
              </rewrite>
          </core>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

And

```
app/code/local/Company/Page/Block/Html/Head.php:

include('Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php');

class Company_Page_block_Html_Head extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product {
    /**
     * Get HEAD HTML with CSS/JS/RSS definitions
     * (actually it also renders other elements, TODO: fix it up or rename this method)
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCssJsHtml()
    {
        echo 'asd';
        return parent::getCssJsHtml();
    }
}
```

But nothing changes, my debug text "asd" is not showing at all, and I have no clue what I might be doing wrong?

I'm running magento 1.9 CE

Comment: Try correcting the case on your </Store>

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to override `getCssJsHtml()`  then your code is totally wrong ..just check below code to override `getCssJsHtml()` method

```
<modules>
    <Company_Metadata>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Company_Metadata>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <metadata>
            <class>Company_Metadata_Block</class>
        </metadata>
        <page>
            <rewrite>
                <html_head>Company_Metadata_Block_Title</html_head>
            </rewrite>
        </page>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

and

```
<?php
class Company_Metadata_Block_Title extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
{
    public function getCssJsHtml()
    {
       echo 'asd';
    return parent::getCssJsHtml();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: Does the file structure change? Right now I have "app/code/local/Company/etc/config.xml" & "app/code/local/Company/Page/Block/Html/Head.php" - do I need to add anything else? Maybe some setting in Magento itself?